# Boot up issue with SD card

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, boot-issues, failure

I had a 16GB SD card and it got bent inside the Pi but I was able to remove it without it splitting into pieces but then it split.

I also had a 32 GB SD card which failed to format and the only why to format it was to put it in a Sony Xperia T3 and connect that to a computer. So I formatted it and then transferred an OS. I then put the SD card in the Pi and this is what appeared on screen when the Pi booted:

[image: Fail!!!]

Here's my [old post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45539/noobs-doesnt-work-the-worst-my-research/45756#45756) which I edited today, why is this happening?

Comment: I imagine you have got a problem with the install on the SD card, I suggest reformat the SD card, re-install and see what happens. Out of interest how are you powering your Pi?

Comment: @DarthVader FAIL! your trick fails! it still stuck and i think android is secretly changing the format

Comment: Check [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23880/raspbian-wont-boot). Last time I had an 179,2 the SD card was broken.

Comment: Check this site: http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards to be sure that your card is compatible with RPi. Also it looks like the boot is working but there isn't root partition. To be sure download raspbian and write image using Win32DiskImager.(Using is simple. Put sdcard, find *.img file and click write button).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your card is broken. I recommend you get your hands on a new one and try again.

Comment: i know what! wait for my another post!

Comment: i solved it like few days ago